# Download not working in my first html site

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, indexing

Hello so I just made an html site that I was thinking could be hosting from my computer for my home where I can stream music and share files but this line of code doesnt work.

```
<h3>Spotify Mod apk</h3>
<a href="Downloads/Spotify.apk" Download>
<img src="pictures/Spotify.png" alt="Spotify.apk" width="100" height="100">
```

I've been scrolling around for about 15 minutes and cant find any solutions the link and img src is correct but it doesnt work.
neither does this work.

```
<h3>BG player</h3>
<a href="Downloads/BG Player.apk" Downloads>
<img src="pictures/Bgplayer.png" width="100" heigh="100">
```

thanks for any help in advance please redirect this sub if I placed it wrong.

Comment: Are you just opening the html page in browser or running a local server where html is being served ?

Comment: I just open it as a html file